# SSMS macro to remove []

Tags: sql-server, macros, ssms, ssms-2012

When SSMS creates a query for a table, all object names have `[]` around them.

They are useful in some rare situations, but names I use for my objects never need them. Then I always need to use replace to remove one and then the other.

Is there a way to do it automatically, be it a macro executed by a shortcut or config SSMS to not create them?

Comment: It won't hurt you now and it may be useful in the future. I would just leave them.

Comment: For the most part I just use ctrl+ H to do a find and replace. Then just replace the [ with nothing.

Comment: Take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21779/sql-server-2012-is-putting-brackets-around-table-and-column-names as @EvanMulawski said, its better having the brackets in case one day you'll code, say, table named 'my table'

Comment: There's no reason NOT to use them.  Why not leave them and save yourself all the time and energy?

Comment: As I said, the names I use never need them. I'll never create a `[my table]` or a `[preço]`. I wanna remove them because they are clumsy and affect readability.